# Using .iloc with 'list' object

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a really big dataframe, looking something like this:

[image]

I want to extract cell values based on a particular **position** and a **column name**. For example, for position 2b, value for DE36.

I made two lists, containg desired rows, and column for extraction, for example

```
row_name =["2b", "87f"]
column_name=["NL984", 'DE36']
```

So, wanted to extract value for *NL984* on *2b* position, and value for *DE36* on *87f* position.

Made a loop and tried something like:

```
df.iloc[df.position==row_name[i],column_name[i]])
```

But I am getting error:

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Is there any other possibility to pass a list argument to .iloc?

Thank you for your help and suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by labels, so `position` column was converted to index:

```
row_name =["2b", "87f"]
column_name=["NL98", 'DE36']

df = df.set_index('position').loc[row_name, column_name]
print (df)
          NL98  DE36
position            
2b           0     8
87f          7    16
```